# Given a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, can we find two orthogonal matrix satisfy that$O_1AO_2$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\det(A)\not=0$, is there existing two orthogonal matrix $O_1$,$O_2$ that satisfy $$O_1AO_2=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 &  &  & \cr  & \lambda_2 &  & \cr  &  & \dots & \cr  &  &  & \lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\lambda_i>0$

how to prove?

Comment: See [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the Singular Value Decomposition.